# Java Regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse out the following using Regexes in Java.

My Test String consists of strings within `"${}"` like for ex: `"Test ${template} in ${xyz} : ${abc}"`

I am trying to use the regex of the form `(\$\{[^\}]+\})` to match it. The current regex does not match anything in the test string.

If I add `(.*?)(\$\{[^\}]+\})(.*?)` to make it ungreedy, it is really not consistent in giving me whatever I want to match.

What is the issue with my regex? How do I fix it?

Comment: I do have escaped the $ and flower braces.

Comment: like this "(.*?)(\\$\\{[^\\}]+\\})(.*?)"

Comment: Can you show ready-to-run example code?

Comment: @Sachin: "flower braces" is new to me :)

Comment: your regex works fine in JavaScript, so it is probably an escaping issue

Comment: Your pattern _does_ match parts of your example input. For example, the following: `System.out.println("Test ${template} in ${xyz} : ${abc}".replaceAll("(\\$\\{[^\\}]+\\})", "@"));` will print: `Test @ in @ : @`

Answer (score 6):

Most of the time when someone asks regular expression questions I ask them to at least consider [Commons Lang StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] names = substringsBetween(theString, "${", "}");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String test = "Test ${template} in ${xyz} : ${abc}";

    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^\\}]+\\}").matcher(test);

    while (m.find())
        System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Outputs:

```
${template}
${xyz}
${abc}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might have to escape the braces as well:

```
jcomeau@intrepid:/usr/src/clusterFix$ python
Python 2.6.7 (r267:88850, Jun 13 2011, 22:03:32) 
[GCC 4.6.1 20110608 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Test ${template} in ${xyz} : ${abc}'
>>> re.compile('\$\{[^}]+\}').findall(s)
['${template}', '${xyz}', '${abc}']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    String test = "Test ${template} in ${xyz} : ${abc}";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{[^}]+\\}");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(test);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String ip="Test ${template} in ${xyz}";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}");
        Matcher m =p.matcher(ip);
        while(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One slash isn't enough. You need two slashes.

Try this regex:

```
\\$\\{.+\\}
```

It checks for strings with ${ and } surrounding text. This filters out blank strings (`${}`) and anything which isn't closed properly.

If you want to check for text infront and behind, try `.+\\$\\{.+\\}.+`